# How to pass array as multiple parameters to function?

Tags: php, function, parsing, call

I have a parameters array:

```
$params[1] = 'param1';
$params[2] = 'param2';
$params[3] = 'param3';
...
$params[N] = 'paramN';
```

I have a caller to various functions:

```
$method->$function( $params );
```

How can I parse the $params array, so multiple (and unlimited) parameters can be passed to any function:

```
$method->$function( $params[1], $params[2], ..., $params[N] );
```

The idea is to utilize the url rewrite like this:

http://domain.com/class/method/parameter/parameter/parameter/...

Answer (score 25, accepted):

You need to use [call_user_func_array](http://php.net/manual/en/function.call-user-func-array.php)

```
call_user_func_array( array($method, $function), $params);
```

Answer (score 19):

As of PHP 5.6 you can use [argument unpacking](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/migration56.new-features.php):

```
function add($a, $b, $c) {
    return $a + $b + $c;
}

$numbers = [1, 2, 3];
echo add(...$numbers);
```