# How do I use variable numbers of parameters in PHP?

Tags: php, string, parameters, parameter-passing

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [PHP function with unlimited number of parameters](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1577383/php-function-with-unlimited-number-of-parameters)
>   [How to pass array as multiple parameters to function?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2720318/how-to-pass-array-as-multiple-parameters-to-function)

I want to create a function with a variable number of parameters in PHP, kinda like a souped up version of `sprintf`. E.g. Where `sprintf` might look like this:

```
$res = sprintf("The number is %d and the string is %s", $num, $str);
```

with an arbitrary number of arguments, I want to do something like this:

```
function my_special_printf($special, $format, ....lots of args...)
{
    // do something with $special here

    return sprintf($format, .. lots of args...);
}
```

Is this possible?

Comment: possible duplicate of [PHP function with unlimited number of parameters](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1577383/php-function-with-unlimited-number-of-parameters) ... have a look at the highest voted answer. Or [Can a PHP function accept an unlimited number of parameters?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3078454/can-a-php-function-accept-an-unlimited-number-of-parameters)

Comment: This question also poses how to pass those parameters on to a further function

Comment: @FelixKling: It is not. This question is also asking about the inverse!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use func_get_args();

http://php.net/manual/en/function.func-get-args.php

This function returns all the parameters in array.

```
<?php
function my_printf() {
   $args = func_get_args();
   $string = &args[0];
   return call_user_func_array('printf', $args);
}
?>
```

or:

```
<?php
function my_printf($string) {
   $args = func_get_args();
   $args = array_shift($args);
   return vsprintf($string, $args);
}
?>
```

Comment: Thanks! That looks good. Can I then just pass an array into the second parameter of sprintf?

Comment: @izb: No, but you can use `call_user_func_array`.

Answer (score 2):

You want the [`func_get_args`](https://www.php.net/func_get_args) function :)